# Magento 2.2.4 fullpage cache settings not appearing in the backend

Tags: admin, full-page-cache, magento2.2.4

Can anybody say why my fullpage cache settings is not appearing?

Thanks.[image]

Comment: Cache settings are not visible in Store->Configuration->General tab rather in Store->Configuration->Advanced->System

Comment: It's already Store->Configuration->Advanced->System. Please see other options.

Comment: @NasirPerwaiz did you checked into default magento 2.2.4 version? may be some conflict over there, or you can check also errors in var/log or server log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured that out why the fullpage cache was not appearing. It's because of Mgtcommere extension that we have installed. When we disabled mgt_varnish, fullpage cache option started coming.

Thanks.